# Dynamic select query with pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning to write dynamic queries so apologies if the below is messy.

My question is why the line below doesn't work. The `@fxPair` variable is underlined in red. In my mind its a string variable so I can't see the problem? Is there a better way of doing this?

```
source pivot(max(Mvalue) for Currency in (@fxPair) as pvt
```

My query:

```
declare @FundsT table (fund nvarchar(10))

insert into @FundsT 
    select SubPot 
    from tblF 
    where Fund = @FundCode
    order by SubPot

declare @fxPair nvarchar(max) = ''

select @fxPair = @fxPair + '[' + Currency + '], ' 
from tblCurrency  
where DateH = @DateHld 
  and FundCode in (select fund from @FundsT)
group by Currency

set @fxPair = SUBSTRING(@fxPair, 1, len(@fxPair) - 1)
--print @fxPair 

select * 
from 
    (select 
         FundCode, IssueGrpType, Currency, Sum(MktValDirty) Mvalue 
     from 
         Holdings_SS
     where 
         DateHolding = @DateHld 
         and FundCode in (select fund from @FundsT)
     group by 
         FundCode, IssueGrpType, Currency) source 
pivot
    (max(Mvalue) for Currency in (@fxPair) as pvt
order by 
    FundCode, IssueGrpType
```

Comment: You asked a question about this query earlier today, the issue there is very much the issue here as well. Your code evaluates to `...in ('[x], [y]')`, what you want is `...in('[x]', '[y]')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass string for pivoted columns. You can check it just write string in ordinary query without using any variables.
The right approach has been described in this article.
[Dynamic pivot](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/)

Whole your query must be a string. In your case you should try something like this

```
DECLARE @dpq AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @dpq = 'select * 
from 
    (select 
         FundCode, IssueGrpType, Currency, Sum(MktValDirty) Mvalue 
     from 
         Holdings_SS
     where 
         DateHolding = @DateHld 
         and FundCode in (select fund from @FundsT)
     group by 
         FundCode, IssueGrpType, Currency) source 
pivot
    (max(Mvalue) for Currency in (' + @fxPair + ') as pvt
order by 
    FundCode, IssueGrpType'
EXEC sp_executesql @dpq
```